# Blocked communication between Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, stream

As my title said I have to implement a program where threads communicate with each other by sending message (serializable object). The fact is that I want threads to be blocked if they don't have a message waiting. I have already checked on Google and I have found 2 solutions : the first one use ObjectStream with PipedStream and the second one use BlockingQueue. My problem is that the 2 solutions seem not to be the best one because PipedStream have lots of bug (I have so much while doing tests) and BlockingQueue do not blocked the thread when the queue is empty.

So has everyone a solution for my problem ?

Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically a producer/consumer, where a thread can be either or both a producer and a consumer.
I believe that `BlockingQueue` offers you the solution you need (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html). Particularly, look at the `put()` and `take()` methods.

Comment: Tanks guy, it works perfectly. Just go over this method ^^ I still have a question : do you know if I have to use mutex when more than one thread produce items in the same queue ?

Comment: A mutex is not necessary, I believe that the implementations of BlockingQueue are thread-safe.

Answer (score 1):

The take method of BlockingQueue does wait

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#take()

Comment: Although you are correct - this is not yet an answer. Please expand - perhaps with code examples.

Comment: Can you please check this example and see if it helps http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html